# Image not showing in chrome. It shows only in firefox

Tags: php, html, css, image

I have a problem with my website. Have defined image on index. Image shows only in firefox. In chrome it doesn't show and I don't know why.. Can anybody help me? Thank you

index.php

```
<div id="advert">
  <a href="#"><img src="img/advertisement/topbanner.jpg" alt="MyWebsite" title="MyWebsite" /></a>
</div> <!-- advert -->
```

CSS

```
#advert {
  height:200px;
  width:460px;
}
```

Comment: ad blockers active?

Comment: Give us the URL so we can check it

Comment: `src="img/advertisement/topbanner.jpg"` such src may lead to image being not displayed if you move from site root to some folder inside it. For instance, on `www.example.com/index.php` browser will try to load image from `www.example.com/img/advertisement/topbanner.jpg` and on `www.example.com/about/index.php` - from `www.example.com/about/img/advertisement/topbanner.jpg`. You may wan t to change src like this:  `src="/img/advertisement/topbanner.jpg"`. Now image will be taken from `www.example.com/img/advertisement/topbanner.jpg` in any case.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like an adblocker-problem. Try to rename the folder "advertisement" and/or the id "advert" into something like foo check if it works then.

Answer (score 0):

Since the code is fine, my guess would be that the image has been saved in CMYK format, instead of RGB.

Or an ad blocker. Since you have an id of `advert`, this will of course be blocked by an adblocker.

Comment: OMG yes, I have adblock enabled... Is there any way to show images with adblock enabled? Thank you very much

Comment: You can probably whitelist your page. Check your ad blocker's docs.

Comment: Either whitelist as @DanielM mentioned, or rename `advert` to something that an adblocker won't pick up

Answer (score -1):

place   (../image folder/ image name)[ ../ infront of folder name]